# Go application hangs when starting subprocess with another user's credentials

Tags: go

I've been using a simple game server management application on Ubuntu 14.04 for the last 6 months or so. After a recent server update & reboot the application would hang on when trying to start a subprocess. After some debugging it seems that whenever I try to start a subprocess with another user's credentials (I'm running as a root) any command will hang.

Here's a simple application to demonstrate what causes the hang:

```
package main
import (
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    proc := exec.Command("ls")

    proc.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{}
    proc.SysProcAttr.Credential = &syscall.Credential{Uid: 1022, Gid: 1023}
    err := proc.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %v", err)
    }
}
```

By removing the  syscall.Credential part, the application will run without any issues.

My question is: is there some platform/update specific reason that causes this behaviour? Is this no longer a correct way to run a subprocess as another user?

EDIT:
Here's the last 5 lines of strace -f

```
[pid  3994] futex(0xc21000a888, FUTEX_WAKE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid  3995] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid  3994] <... futex resumed> )       = 1
[pid  3995] futex(0xc21000a888, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  3994] select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 20}) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid  3994] futex(0x7f615c51a4f8, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL
```

So apparently if I'm interpreting this right it's blocking at futex_wait.

Comment: Get a stack trace to see where exactly it's blocked. Check your syslog and dmesg.

Comment: Waiting on a futex doesn't mean anything. What does the stack trace show?

Answer (score 1):

You should execute your application with strace.  So `strace myapp` and see where it locks up.  It could be you have something else that's forking before your application executes, which is causing it to hang.

Comment: you need `strace -f` to follow a multithreaded program (and because it's multithreaded, go programs can't fork).